# PlaceholderView contain many views

Tags: ios, view, storyboard, containers

I have a placeholder view and 7 buttons  [image: See the figure below:]

Press first button for appear first view in placeholder view
Second - second view in placeholder view etc. I need exactly this way (no tab bar, no segmented control)

How to implement this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `seven` views in the `interfaceBuilder` or `storyboard` and connect an `outlets` with your `viewcontroller`.. And write `IBAction` methods for all buttons in your `view` and change the `subview` of `placeholderview` for everytime when the button pressed. You can achieve this, either create a separate action method for all buttons or set a tag for each button and call the same method and change the view. Check my below code. it will help you.

Set a `tag` for each button in the `interface builder.` For instance, I set it like 1,2,3,... respectively.

```
// action method for all the button look like this..
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    for (UIView *view in placeholderView.subViews) {
         [view removeFromSuperView];
    }
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    switch(button.tag) {
        case 1:
           [placeholderView addSubView:subView1];
         break;
        case 2:
           [placeholderView addSubView:subView2];
         break;
        case 3:
           [placeholderView addSubView:subView3];
         break;
    }
}
```